# Cannot change textcolor for Text in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need change Text color for UI Text to red, I tried on Indicator and script but the text color still have black color. What is wrong here ?

```
continueText.color = Red.color;
```

or

```
coreText.text = "<color="+textColor+">textContent"</color>";
```

or

[image]

Comment: does changing color work with the default font? (you seem to be using some custom one)

Comment: Yes, with Arial font the color is correct.

Comment: does that font importer/inspector window allow setting it dynamic, or some other related option, maybe color then works

Comment: from original font I make a editable font copy and use this font. With original font, set color work fine

Comment: i downloaded the same font, http://www.dafont.com/nokia-cellphone.font , changing color from inspector works for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, Font include `texture` and `metarial` is packed. Here I make a editable copy of original font so that the metarial is unpacked. We need add metarial to `Metarial box` under `color box` choice to change color.

Thanks to @mgear for your help.